# Changing DAC output how far, how fast, how to tell

Tags: dac

If I had say a 100MHz DAC I can't just change the output from 0V to max V in 10ns, at least I think I remember you can't do that in real life.  How do you understand what you can do from a datasheet?  I feel like I remember reading about this once but I don't remember what it's called.  I assume it's load dependent as well and I'm thinking of this in the context of having a 50 Ohm piece of coax connected to the output both source and end terminated.

Comment: A 100MHz DAc could also mean a serial DAC with 100MHz clock speed so name devices and allow folk to help.

Comment: I don't have one in mind I thought this was a common limitation of all DAC, basically how far can you switch in a clock cycle.

Comment: What do you specifically mean by "a 100MHz DAC"?

Comment: A DAC who's input sample clock is running at 100MHz, how about this for an example it's close to what I was thinking of.  http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9763_9765_9767.pdf

Comment: Output settling time to 0.1% is 35ns for that DAC, Is that the data you are generically looking for? Output rise time (10% to 90%) is 2.5 ns.

Comment: That sounds close, but I'm not sure what that means.  Does that mean I can get to any full output voltage value within 35ns?  a 2.5ns rise time would suggest I could get anywhere within a single clock cycle

Comment: The rise and fall times (if you'd read the data sheet) are specified from 10% to 90% starting to aiming voltages and clearly to reach 0.1% (due to stray capacitance for instance), it takes a lot longer.

Comment: Thanks I can read a datasheet, and fully understand what a 10-90 rise time is...

Comment: So, your not so "confused" then LOL

Comment: There is a good series of articles on DACs at http://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/archive/tags/DAC%2bEssentials

Answer (score 1):

The word your looking for is slew rate. That is how fast you can change from one voltage to another. It is usually measured I'm V/ns. The DAC should have this is the data sheet.

Comment: I think you mean "Slew" rate.